# Dosbox with C-compiler and gui

Tags: dosbox

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and Dosbox 0.74-3. Is is possible to install GUI for this dosbox? Can one install C compiler for this box?

Comment: Welcome! Your question doesn’t really fit in the scope of this SE, because it involves new software — while Dosbox aims to emulate PCs and DOS, it does so with a limited scope (running DOS games), so it’s not necessarily suitable for general-purpose DOS usage. Many general-purpose programs *will* work fine, but if they don’t you’re on your own. If you want to make this more relevant to this SE, I suggest asking about MS-DOS development environments in general, but please explain what you’re ultimately interested in doing.

Comment: You most likely should look at a full DOS installation in a virtual machine under Ubuntu.

Comment: For what it's worth, I keep a Windows 98 virtual machine (running under Fusion Pro 11.5 on my Macbook Pro) with the OpenWatcom C/C++ (www.openwatcom.org) compiler/IDE installed and it works great.  I would suspect you could do the same under Ubuntu using VirtualBox (www.virtualbox.org).

Comment: Yes. Borland C, for example.

Comment: Open Watcom C/C++ also can run natively on Linux and compile for DOS, letting you use whatever tooling you want. (Open Watcom is unusual in that a single installation supports all targets by default.) That's how I do my retro-hobby programming. I just develop on Linux and have my build automation include a script which copies the built binary into DOSBox and launches it from outside. (For automated testing, DOSBox has `serial1=nullmodem server:127.0.0.1 port:4543 transparent:1` set and that's how test builds report to the harness via COM1.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For the GUI: you can run Windows 3.1 in a Dosbox.
- For a C compiler: you can use any C compiler of the era, for example Watcom C, djgpp, or Borland C.
- For an IDE: Borland C had a quite good character IDE.

Comment: If the OP’s goal is to use the GUI for development, it’s worth pointing out that the version of Dosbox packaged in Ubuntu can’t run DOS programs inside Windows.

Comment: Quick C was another C compiler and IDE from Microsoft for MS-DOS. But of course djgpp or watcom would be much more superior in terms of developer experience.